# How do I migrate reusable containers approach from 2.4.0 to 3.4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, integration-testing, testcontainers

This used to work back in Testcontainers 2.4.0. However, the image it used is now gone and I'm forced to upgrade to the newest one which is 3.4.0. The problem is `new ContainerBuilder<T>` is no longer possible. There is no longer `TestcontainerDatabase`, etc.

```cs
public abstract class Container<T> : IDisposable where T : DockerContainer
{
    readonly SemaphoreSlim _syncLock = new(1, 1);
    readonly ITestOutputHelperAccessor _outputHelperAccessor;

    bool _running;

    protected Container(ITestOutputHelperAccessor outputHelperAccessor, string name)
    {
        _outputHelperAccessor = outputHelperAccessor;
        Name = name;
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder<T>();
        NewContainer = new(() => ConfigureContainer(containerBuilder.WithName(name).WithCleanUp(AzureIdentity.IsBuildAgent)).Build());
    }

    protected abstract ContainerBuilder<T> ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder<T> containerBuilder);

    public string Name { get; }
    protected Lazy<T> NewContainer { get; }
    protected ContainerListResponse? ExistingContainer { get; private set; }

    public bool IsNew => !_running
        ? throw new InvalidOperationException($"Call {nameof(EnsureStarted)} first.")
        : ExistingContainer == null;

    public async Task EnsureStarted()
    {
        await _syncLock.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            if (_running)
                return;

            using var configuration = new DockerClientConfiguration();
            using var client = configuration.CreateClient();
            var containers = await client.Containers.ListContainersAsync(new() { All = true });
            ExistingContainer = containers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Names.Contains($"/{Name}"));
            if (ExistingContainer != null)
            {
                if (ExistingContainer.State != "running")
                {
                    _outputHelperAccessor.OutputHelper?.WriteLineWithTimestamp($"Starting {Name} container ...");
                    var started = await client.Containers.StartContainerAsync(ExistingContainer.ID, new());
                    started.Should().BeTrue();
                }
                else
                    _outputHelperAccessor.OutputHelper?.WriteLineWithTimestamp($"Using {Name} container ...");

                _running = true;
                return;
            }

            _outputHelperAccessor.OutputHelper?.WriteLineWithTimestamp($"Creating {Name} container ...");
            await NewContainer.Value.StartAsync();
            _running = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            _syncLock.Release();
        }
    }

    public async Task EnsureStopped()
    {
        await _syncLock.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            if (!_running)
                return;

            if (NewContainer.Value.State == TestcontainersStates.Running)
            {
                await NewContainer.Value.StopAsync();
                _running = false;
                return;
            }

            using var configuration = new DockerClientConfiguration();
            using var client = configuration.CreateClient();
            var containers = await client.Containers.ListContainersAsync(new() { All = true });
            ExistingContainer = containers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Names.Contains($"/{Name}"));
            if (ExistingContainer != null)
            {
                if (ExistingContainer.State == "running")
                {
                    _outputHelperAccessor.OutputHelper?.WriteLineWithTimestamp($"Stopping {Name} container ...");
                    var stopped = await client.Containers.StopContainerAsync(ExistingContainer.ID, new());
                    stopped.Should().BeTrue();
                }
                _running = false;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _syncLock.Release();
        }
    }
    
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _syncLock.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

public abstract class DbContainer<T> : Container<T> where T : TestcontainerDatabase
{
    protected DbContainer(ITestOutputHelperAccessor outputHelperAccessor, string name) : base(outputHelperAccessor, name) { }

    public string ConnectionString => ExistingContainer == null
        ? NewContainer.Value.ConnectionString
        : Policy
            .Handle<Exception>()
            .WaitAndRetry(Backoff.LinearBackoff(500.Milliseconds(), 5))
            .Execute(() => FindConnectionString(ExistingContainer));

    protected abstract string FindConnectionString(ContainerListResponse existingContainer);
}

public class MsSqlContainer : DbContainer<MsSqlTestcontainer>
{
    const string Password = "Password@123";
    readonly MsSqlTestcontainerConfiguration _configuration;

    public MsSqlContainer(ITestOutputHelperAccessor outputHelperAccessor, string name) : base(outputHelperAccessor, name) =>
        _configuration = new()
        {
            Database = name,
            Password = Password
        };

    protected override ContainerBuilder<MsSqlTestcontainer> ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder<MsSqlTestcontainer> containerBuilder) =>
        containerBuilder.WithDatabase(_configuration);

    protected override string FindConnectionString(ContainerListResponse existingContainer)
    {
        var port = existingContainer.Ports.First();
        return $"Server=127.0.0.1,{port.PublicPort};Database={Name};User Id=sa;Password={Password}";
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _configuration.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}

public class RedisContainer : DbContainer<RedisTestcontainer>
{
    readonly RedisTestcontainerConfiguration _configuration = new();

    public RedisContainer(ITestOutputHelperAccessor outputHelperAccessor, string name) : base(outputHelperAccessor, name) { }

    protected override ContainerBuilder<RedisTestcontainer> ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder<RedisTestcontainer> containerBuilder) =>
        containerBuilder.WithDatabase(_configuration);

    protected override string FindConnectionString(ContainerListResponse existingContainer)
    {
        var port = existingContainer.Ports.First();
        return $"127.0.0.1:{port.PublicPort}";
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _configuration.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Here is what I tried but it spawns an additional container named `testcontainers` and also when the tests complete, it kills the container, which completely kills the purpose of the whole thing.

```cs
public abstract class ReusableContainerBase<TBuilderEntity, TContainerEntity, TConfigurationEntity> : IDisposable
    where TBuilderEntity : ContainerBuilder<TBuilderEntity, TContainerEntity, TConfigurationEntity>
    where TContainerEntity : IContainer
    where TConfigurationEntity : IContainerConfiguration
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new(1, 1);
    private TContainerEntity? _container;

    readonly ITestOutputHelperAccessor _outputHelperAccessor;
    readonly string _containerName;

    protected ReusableContainerBase(ITestOutputHelperAccessor outputHelperAccessor, string containerName)
    {
        _outputHelperAccessor = outputHelperAccessor;
        _containerName = containerName;
    }

    public bool IsNew { get; private set; }
    public string? ConnectionString { get; private set; }

    public abstract ContainerBuilder<TBuilderEntity, TContainerEntity, TConfigurationEntity> Builder { get; }

    private async Task StartContainerAsync()
    {
        _outputHelperAccessor.OutputHelper?.WriteLineWithTimestamp($"Starting {_containerName} container ...");
        _container = Builder.Build();
        await _container.StartAsync();
        IsNew = true;
        ConnectionString = await GetConnectionStringAsync();
    }

    private async Task StopContainerAsync(TContainerEntity container)
    {
        _outputHelperAccessor.OutputHelper?.WriteLineWithTimestamp($"Stopping {_containerName} container ...");
        await container.StopAsync();
        IsNew = false;
        ConnectionString = null;
    }

    public async Task EnsureStarted()
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            var container = await GetContainerAsync();
            if (container == null || container.State != TestcontainersStates.Running)
                await StartContainerAsync();
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    public async Task EnsureStopped()
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            var container = await GetContainerAsync();
            if (container != null && container.State == TestcontainersStates.Running)
                await StopContainerAsync(container);
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
    
    private async Task<TContainerEntity?> GetContainerAsync()
    {
        if (_container == null || _container.State != TestcontainersStates.Running)
            _container = await FindContainerAsync();

        return _container;
    }

    public async Task<string?> GetConnectionStringAsync()
    {
        var container = await GetContainerAsync();
        return container != null ? FindConnectionString(container) : null;
    }
    
    private async Task<TContainerEntity?> FindContainerAsync()
    {
        using var configuration = new DockerClientConfiguration();
        using var client = configuration.CreateClient();
        var containers = await client.Containers.ListContainersAsync(new() { All = true });

        foreach (var container in containers)
        {
            if (container.Names.Any(n => n.EndsWith(_containerName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            {
                return _container;
            }
        }

        return default;
    }

    protected abstract string FindConnectionString(TContainerEntity container);

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _semaphore.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

public class ReusableMsSqlContainer : ReusableContainerBase<MsSqlBuilder, MsSqlContainer, MsSqlConfiguration>
{
    const string Password = "Password@123";

    readonly string _name;

    public ReusableMsSqlContainer(ITestOutputHelperAccessor outputHelperAccessor, string containerName) : base(outputHelperAccessor, containerName) => _name = containerName;

    public override ContainerBuilder<MsSqlBuilder, MsSqlContainer, MsSqlConfiguration> Builder =>
        new MsSqlBuilder()
            .WithName(_name)
            .WithPassword(Password);

    protected override string FindConnectionString(MsSqlContainer container)
    {
        var mappedPort = container.GetMappedPublicPort(MsSqlBuilder.MsSqlPort);
        return $"Server=127.0.0.1,{mappedPort};Database={_name};User Id=sa;Password={Password}";
    }
}

public class ReusableRedisContainer : ReusableContainerBase<RedisBuilder, RedisContainer, RedisConfiguration>
{
    readonly string _name;

    public ReusableRedisContainer(ITestOutputHelperAccessor outputHelperAccessor, string containerName) : base(outputHelperAccessor, containerName) => _name = containerName;

    public override ContainerBuilder<RedisBuilder, RedisContainer, RedisConfiguration> Builder =>
        new RedisBuilder()
            .WithName(_name);

    protected override string FindConnectionString(RedisContainer container)
    {
        var mappedPort = container.GetMappedPublicPort(RedisBuilder.RedisPort);
        return $"127.0.0.1:{mappedPort}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility?tabs=windows-server-2022%2Cwindows-11

Comment: @jdweng, what does this have to do with what I asked?

Comment: You have a docker database that you are migrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new database modules do not share a common interface or inherit from a common class (yet). You find more details about this in the following [GitHub pull request](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet/pull/920).

> Here is what I tried but it spawns an additional container named `testcontainers` and also when the tests complete, it kills the container, which completely kills the purpose of the whole thing.

The [Resource Reaper](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/api/resource-reaper/) takes care of remaining Docker resources after each  test session. If needed, you have the option to disable it through custom configurations, such as using the environment variable `TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true`. However, please be aware that we do not recommend this approach as described in our [best practices](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/api/best_practices/).

It is important to note that the method `FindContainerAsync()` cannot return a `TContainerEntity` (at least not the type you expect). The Docker API call `ListContainersAsync` provides a Docker entity rather than the actual Testcontainers entity. Those types are entirely different. For information about reusable support, please refer to this [issue](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet/issues/407).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that really explains things. Would you suggest to me another approach with a code snippet?

Comment: The best solution is to natively support it in Testcontainers for .NET. This involves internally identifying the Docker resources for reuse (using a hash), assigning the Docker inspect responses to the related field. Any external approach is more complex and requires awkward workarounds.